# Two "search" entries in resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf, dhclient

I am using 12.04 and have a problem with my `resolv.conf`

There are 2 search lines there. But I can only explain one. I would like to get the other one removed.

```
carsten@myubuntubox:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search aaaa.bbb.example.net
search something
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.5
```

I can't explain the search `aaaa.bbb.example.net` Where does it come from?

The last 3 lines (like I want come from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`  This is good.

But where is the other search line coming from? In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient` I removed the requests for domain-name-servers, domain-search, but the lines are still in there.

Should I remove the dhcp6.domain-search as well?

Answer (score 2):

Add the line

```
supersede domain-search "something";
```

to the end of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Perhaps your `aaaa.bbb.example.net` comes from your (ISP's) DHCP server?

Or if you want something like

```
search some.thing something.else
```

in your `resolv.conf`, add a line like

```
supersede domain-search "some.thing", "something.else";
```

in your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Comment: 8 years later, still the only answer that works! Ubuntu 18.04 LOL

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have two `search` lines is that one (the first one) is generated by resolvconf dynamically, based on its own configuration and on nameserver information supplied to it by interface configurers; and the other (the second one) is appended verbatim from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`. Only the last one is used by the resolver. Hence, the first one is inoperative.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you were looking for... but here you go anwyay

You can delete the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and create a normal file with the contents you want.

On that note, I've accidentally done that somehow and was wondering if you could tell me what your `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink is pointing to so I can fix mine.

Comment: On my 12.04 installation, /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink pointing to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Comment: Interesting... I don't have this file /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Comment: @Corey: You can try `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` - in my case it recreated /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf and symlinked /etc/resolv.conf to it.